# download image files from path stored in sql server database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I am making a web form application that allows a user to upload image file to a folder and store its path in database.
there is a data-list that is populated by the image path.
I want the functionality to download image when it is selected from data-list.
I am new to it and didn't get clear guidance from other questions.

Kindly help me.

Here is my code for uploading file

```
try
{
    if (FileUploadzz.HasFile)
    {

        Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        string strguid = g.ToString();
        string uniqueString = strguid + FileUploadzz.FileName;

        FileUploadzz.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\AllUploads\AllUserImages\" + uniqueString));
        DataClasses1DataContext db2 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        Picture p = new Picture();
        p.picturePath = "http://localhost:12237/AllUploads//AllUserImages/" + uniqueString;

        db2.Pictures.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        db2.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

i have a button in my datalist itemtemplate that i want to use for downloading that specific image

i need help on downloading the image when button is clicked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). Http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To show list of files in aspx

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" >
<ItemTemplate>
  <a href='/download/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>'>
      <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>
  </a>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In the code-behind

```
DataList1.DataSource = ...;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

where FileName is a name of column in the database and /download is a folder of files.

To download using a button with onclick event, replace a-tag with

```
<input type="button" value="download" 
     onclick="window.location.href='/download/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileName") %>'">
```

Comment: i have a button in my datalist itemtemplate that i want to use for downloading that specific image

I need help on downloading the image when button is clicked.
 I have  image control and a button (button1) in item template of datalist. 
I have already populated my datalist succesfully with images.
please let me know how to download that image on OnCLlick event of that button1.